# React TreeView JSON Data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is there a way to create a TreeView navigation using React?

my data is returned as:

```
[{
    "make" : "BMW",
    "year" : "2020",
    "type" : "used"
 },
 {
    "make" : "BMW",
    "year" : "2022",
    "type" : "new"
 },
 {
   "make" : "lexus",
   "year" : "2022",
   "type" : "used"
 },
 {
   "make" : "lexus",
   "year" : "2022",
   "type" : "used"
 }
```

I want the tree to look like

```
 used
      2022
         bmw
         lexus
   new
       2022
          BMW
```

I can't change the output format, so it has be done in the response object.

Comment: try out this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-view

Comment: I need to be displayed in a TreeView control on the web, not in  JSON format to the user